# How to extract particular string value from url in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function which will return me the URL, from that url I need to extract value of app_id

URL : https://redsuite.com/login?org=delivery&app_id=rtl5454gfghf&comp=fida

I am new to angular any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public getApiProvider() {
    const appId = null;
    const options = {
        params: new HttpParams().set(AppService.APP_NAME_LABEL, AppService.APP_NAME)
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<ApiProvider>(
        `${this.appService.getData().apiURL}/red/verify/login`,
        options
    )pipe(
      //need to extract app_id here and assign it to appId const
    );
   //URL : https://redsuite.com/login?org=delivery&**app_id=rtl5454gfghf**&comp=fida
}
```

how to extract app_id using angular pipe() within the same function

Answer (score 0):

though i don't see what your'e trying to achieve since you're terminating the function by returning the HTTP call expression,

first change the appId to let if u want to reassign it, then u can use the tap operator alongside URLSearchParams as follows -

```
return this.httpClient.get<ApiProvider>(
        `${this.appService.getData().apiURL}/red/verify/login`,
        options
    )pipe(
      tap((url) => this.appId = new SearchUrlParams(url).get("app_id"))
    );
```

Comment: thank you ! do we have any angular component like SearchUrlParams ..what is SearchUrlParams?